# How to only display traffic from particular sources in a Google Analytics dashboard widget

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I can't believe this is as difficult as I'm finding it to be, so I must be missing something obvious!

I want to track data from two particular ads, one on TheSixFifty.com and one in the mountain view voice email newsletter. I've gotten as far as identifying these two sources in a table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3l3Q.jpg

I want to *only* display those two sources, so I thought a filter would be the way to do that, set up like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYaij.jpg

But that results in this sad, sad empty table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ie7k.jpg

Please tell me what I am doing wrong! Does "containing" not mean what I think it does? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - it *is* something simple!

Your filter contains an **AND** statement, so it will only show data where the source contains **BOTH** `mv-voice.com` and `TheSixFifty.com.`

Your filter should look like:

> Only show Source Matching RegEx:
>
> > `(TheSixFifty|mv-voice)\.com`

Here's a great intro to Regular Expressions from [Robbin Steif's guide](https://www.lunametrics.com/regex-book/Regular-Expressions-Google-Analytics.pdf), they'll be incredibly useful for any analysis.